# Is it normal practise to use CLI in production code?

Tags: node.js

I want to use [Shuoosh](https://squoosh.app/) in my code to resize/optimize/convert to WebP my photos (as I know it's wonderful). But there's a small problem. There isn't still npm package. The only way to use it without theirs website is [cli](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/squoosh/tree/dev/cli). So, is it a good idea to write something like in code?

```js
const {exec} = require(`child_process`);

exec(`@squoosh/cli some.jpg [options]`);
```

Or it's better to use less effective sharp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is anything inside that exec string that could be inputted by a user, then no.

Ultimately it's probably not a good idea, especially not for anything that would need to scale; but in your case it should be fine for a small project. Just be VERY CAREFUL about what can go in that exec string.

Every single word, character, and whatever that goes inside that function call should be generated by the server. Don't let users specify a filename, but it would be Ok if the server generates its own file name and uses that.

Comment: Thanks. Of course, I won't use anything inputted by user